# Opencart 2.0 - PayPal Commerce Platform card payment fields not showing

Tags: paypal, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I have PayPal Commerce Platform module installed on OpenCart 2.0. But during checkout, if the user wants to use card payment, the card form fields are not showing.

**Below are image examples**

[image: Card Payment Option]

**No Field to add card details**

[image]

I will appreciate your help on sorting out this issue

Answer (score 0):

If it's trying to render PayPal's Advanced Credit and Debit Card fields, the console should have details about why it's failing. You may simply need to [enable the account for card processing](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/integrate#link-enableyouraccounttoacceptcardpayments). Sandbox accounts are enabled by default now.

For going live, there is a link in the note to the production onboarding: https://www.paypal.com/bizsignup/entry/product/ppcp